# Unknown under ikev2 VPN profiles

Tags: vpn

I've recently established a VPN server with [setup-ipsec-vpn](https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn) and everything works just fine. The IOS vpn client is installed with a *.mobileconfig autogenerated by the script ([Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/business/documentation/Configuration-Profile-Reference.pdf)). The only thing that bothers me is the Unknown under my Server Description. Any methods so I can change this value?

[image: Screenshot1]

Comment: Have you created an issue on the GitHub repo?  That's probably the best way to get your concern addressed.

Comment: I've tried posting it in the issues section on the Github Repo, though, the author wasn't really sure where to set this particular value. In the [issue](https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn/issues/995), one of the comment mentioned that it may be a key value pair of the mobileconfig XML file.